# What's the difference between these two return statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm self-studying cs61a and working on the Q5 from here: https://cs61a.org/lab/lab04/

For berry_finder question, my solution is below:

```
def berry_finder(t):     
    if label(t) == 'berry':
        return True
    else:
        for branch in branches(t):
            return berry_finder(branch)
    return False
```

But when I run it on a case that the tree has `berry`,
for example:
`sproul = tree('roots', [tree('branch1', [tree('leaf'), tree('berry')]), tree('branch2')])`. It returns `False`.

I found the solution is actually below:

```
def berry_finder(t):    
    if label(t) == 'berry':
        return True
    else:
        for branch in branches(t):
            if berry_finder(branch):
                return True
    return False
```

Found out that the difference is the statement under the `for branch in branches(t)` loop. So I wonder why my solution is wrong. Please help!

Comment: Ask yourself this: Does the first version have a chance *not* to ``return`` on the first ``branch``? Does the second version have a chance *not* to ``return`` on the first ``branch``?

Comment: return leaves the function. a `for a in branches(t): return ...` will only ever check the first `a` and then return. Your second code does somthing different. (if it would work like this at all). Your question is not a [mre] - you do not call it anyhow.

Answer (score -1):

the first if statement will never return true because "berry" is located in branch.
Also in your else statement you loop in branches but you do not return any thing so the cod dose not leave the function and reaches the line "return false" which return false even though "berry" is existed.